# Why does my excel file open with a new name while debugging?

Tags: excel, vsto

I have created a simple VSTO project based on a Binary Excel file, the name of the file is Text.xlsb. When I run this in debug mode from VS, the file gets renamed as Test1.xlsb and opens, also my open even is not getting fired, but the Activate event if triggered.

Can some one help me to resolve this? I think VSTO is treating the Excel file as a template and assigning a different name on open.

Comment: Version of VSTO? Of Excel? Are you sure you selected the option to create a new workbook and not a new template when creating the project?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013, Excel 2013 and yes 200% i have selected New workbook with Binary Excel format